# Increase the speed of this python code for text processing

Tags: python, performance, multithreading

I need to iterate through a file of words and perform tests on them.

```
import multiprocessing
import datetime

class line_Worker(object):
    def worker(self, chunks):
        for l in chunks:
            num = 0
            for num in range(100):
                print l, num
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('words.txt')] #opens file and saves to list
    chunkNum = len(lines) / 26
    wordLists = [lines[x:x + chunkNum] for x in range(0, len(lines), chunkNum)]#divides list by 4 and saves to list of lists
    jobs = []
    timeStart = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    for i in range(27):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=line_Worker().worker, args=(wordLists[i],))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in jobs:
        p.join()  # wait for the process to finish

    timeStop = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    print timeStart
    print timeStop
```

I have a problem set of 35,498,500 individual lines, and I need to try to get it to run in roughly 3 minutes. The current run times are 16 minutes.

Is there any way to speed this up? Thanks all!

Comment: If you are trying to be performant, why are you printing?

Comment: Beside the obvious performance issue when you print, you're printing in a multi-threaded setting. That means that there is no way to determine the order in which stuff appears on screen. Is that fine?

Comment: Have you measured which part of those 16 mins is spent in the reading in of the words.txt file?

Comment: Its negligible sub 1 second, Im gonna try taking the print statements out and see what happens. I will post back.

Comment: The purpose of the script is to demonstrate what a dictionary attack would look like to  illustrate an internet safety demo

Comment: What happens if you run the script redirecting stdout (using `python script.py > /tmp/file.txt`)? Writing large quantities of text to a terminal can be very slow.

Comment: The answer is the bottleneck is the print statement. Thanks all!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of the print statement fixed it thanks all!

```
import multiprocessing
import datetime

class line_Worker(object):
    def worker(self, chunks):
        for l in chunks:
            num = 0
            for num in range(100):
                print l, num#clearing this made the time 4 seconds thanks all!!
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('words.txt')] #opens file and saves to list
    chunkNum = len(lines) / 26
    wordLists = [lines[x:x + chunkNum] for x in range(0, len(lines), chunkNum)]#divides list by 4 and saves to list of lists
    jobs = []
    timeStart = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    for i in range(27):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=line_Worker().worker, args=(wordLists[i],))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in jobs:
        p.join()  # wait for the process to finish

    timeStop = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    print timeStart
    print timeStop
```